# How to check if a video is stabilized or not?

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

I was wondering how to detect camera motion in a youtube video.

I want to read in an youtube link process the video and tell the user if it was filmed using a tripod or if it was super shakey.

Do anyone know where I would even start? It might not even be possible?

Comment: In this case, the best place to start is doing some research and making an attempt at solving your problem. As it is right now, this is a ***very*** broad question, and is probably off-topic for SO because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Just spitballing here, but I'd start by capturing frames that are close together at various points throughout the video.

You would take the frames from each section and compare them to each other for variations in composition, dunno how to best go about that.. I'd probably start with like colour detection in various spots?  anyway, start building a "difference score"

once you've gone through the frames for each section you sampled, you'll have a "difference score" and you can then start trying to figure out what the cut off point is for detecting a shakey video.

you probably couldn't do this anywhere close to realtime, so be prepared to have a bit of a wait period while the video processes.

Answer (score 0):

Take some images each seconds (avoid to take it at a fixed frequency, because if the film has a move frequency, ie: if we are on a boat and we film during high waves)

After you can convert it to black and white (not gray levels) and compare it. Using the position of the minor color. (But it ain't gonna work fine)

Usually we use, edge detection : http://fr.mathworks.com/discovery/edge-detection.html and compare some of it. To see what is the scene and work together and waht is not. You must find "interest points" an calculate the vector between two frames. Some of this vector will move together. It's an object. Now you have to find which object if the scene.